# Keyframe jumps back to Pose Mode

Tags: timeline

I am working on an animation and have a problem with the keys in the timeline. Until now it was always like the last keyframe in the timeline was fixed if there did not come any keyframes after that. But now the last keyframe does not stay in position. Its always changing to the rest position after the last keyframe. Thats really tedious because the only way I found to handle that is to always copy the last keyframe... Does anyone know what I have to change that the pose stays in position after my last keyframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of this behaviour only if there is an action strip on the NLA editor with the rest pose as last keyframe and extrapolation set to "Hold", while the Edited Action has extrapolation set to "Nothing".

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t find an Action Strip with a rest pose as last keyframe. But it works now with extrapolation set to "hold". I did not know that this is necessary when I don´t push down the action. So now I know it because of you :)